# How can I keep anchor alive in pagination links?

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

Here is my code in the controller:

```
$unique_products = unique_products::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(10);
```

And here is my code in the view:

```
{{$unique_products->render()}}
```

And here is my current URL:

```
http://www.example.com/products#anchor
```

---

My problem is, when I click on other pages (which are in pagination box), the anchor is deleted from the URL. It will be something like this:

```
http://www.example.com/products?page=1
```

Anyway, how can I keep the anchor exist? I want this:

```
http://www.example.com/products?page=1#anchor
```

How can I do that?

Comment: I'm presuming that your pagination links are generated automatically by either your render or another helper. You'd either need to overwrite these and append the anchor you wish to have, manually create the pagination links with the anchor, or use JS to replace the URLs with the URL + an anchor. Without knowing more of your code, I'd be speculating an answer though.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to display your links like shown in the [official docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/pagination#displaying-pagination-results) because when you want to `navigate` through pages your `unique_products` has access to the `fragment` method which can retrieve fragments from the url which are actually Hashtags (#) and then append them to every page change url:

```
{{ $unique_products->fragment('foo')->links() }}
```